# How to integrate a function for multiple upper limits using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numerical-integration

Suppose I have an integrand, and I want to integrate the function using various upper limits. In my code, I have the upper limit as 1. But I want to evaluate the integral using 1, 2, 4, 6. How do I do that? Do I use the map function? I've tried setting the upper limit as an array but I get all kinds of errors. This is my code using only 1. Any help is appreciated.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def integrand(x, a, b):
    return a*x**2 + b

a = 2
b = 1
I = quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(a,b))
```

Comment: Why not just call the function multiple times? I don't really understand what you're hoping to accomplish here. Is the question somehow specific to the task of integrating a function? Or is it just a matter of general technique for getting multiple results with different inputs?

Comment: Well because I'm suppose to graph the result. But I want a general case because what if I had to integrate for many inputs? But yes I want a general technique for different inputs.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for something like `partial` from `functools` library. With that you can define a new function (eg `I2`) with all the inputs fixed, except for your upper bound

Comment: I guess, my issue is how do I assign each value of the my list of upper limit values i want to evaluate. Kinda like a for loop in MATLAB. I never really used Python, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to simply call `quad` with each of your desired upper bounds.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
# typing is just for clarity
from typing import List

def integrand(x, a, b):
    return a*x**2 + b

def multi_integrate(a,b,lb:float, ub_ls:List[float]) -> List:
    results = []
    # loop through all upper bounds
    for ub in ub_ls:
        results.append(quad(integrand,lb,ub,args=(a,b)))
    return results

# variables
a = 2
b = 1
# upper bound and list of lower bounds
lb = 0
ub_ls = [1,2,4,6]
# get a list of your integral results
I = multi_integrate(a,b, lb,ub_ls)
```

I hope this is your intended functionality.

Comment: Yea, this is what I want! But why do I get a syntax error in "b:float"....specifically in the colon?

Comment: Sorry, my initial post misunderstood what `a` and `b` were, since they traditionally denote the upper and lower bounds, but it looks like you use them as other variables. I edited my post to correct this, but evidently you grabbed the code before I did so. It should work now, given that you are providing single numbers for a, b, and the lower bound, and a list for the upper bounds.

Comment: i get this error:  $python main.py
  File "main.py", line 8
    def multi_integrate(a,b,lb:float, ub_ls:List[float]) -> List:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you include the `from typing import List` statement? I only added the types for clarity but they may be causing issues if you aren't familiar with them. You may want to just remove them, changing the line `def multi_integrate(a,b,lb:float, ub_ls:List[float]) -> List:` to `def multi_integrate(a,b,lb,ub_ls):` to see if that was causing issues. It may also be an issue with int->float.